# Database not starting in init.d

Tags: postgresql, init.d

I am attempting to setup a small postgresql database on a beaglebone black.  The application is slow so I am storing the database on a 64GB microsd card.  I formatted the drive, mounted it all correctly.

I logged in as postgres

sudo su postgres

create the database cluster

```
./initdb /data   # the mountpoint is /data
```

It all seemed to work correctly.  I can

```
./postgres -D /data and the cluster seems to start correctly.
```

I want the database to start in init.d so I edited the three lines in /etc/postgresql/9.1/postgresql.conf and pointed the three entries to /data.  When I start the machine the database fails with the following in the log file

```
autovacuum launcher started
database system is ready
incomplete startup packet
received smart shutdown request
autovacuum launcher shutting down
database system is shutdown
```

I have obviously missed something, any pointer to where to find what I missed would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The startup scripts will pick up your postgres instance if you create it with the tools that are meant to work with these scripts, that is:

- [pg_createcluster](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/pg_createcluster.8.html) to create an instance (or cluster in postgres terminology).
- [pg_ctlcluster](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/pg_ctlcluster.8.html) to control an instance.

For example, instead of running `initdb`, and assuming you have installed the `postgresql-9.1` package, you're expected to do:

```
sudo pg_createcluster --datadir=/data 9.1 mycluster
```

Then a specific directory will be created for that instance under `/etc/postgresql/9.1` for `postgresql.conf` and other configuration files, among which a `start.conf` with these contents:

```
# Automatic startup configuration
# auto: automatically start/stop the cluster in the init script
# manual: do not start/stop in init scripts, but allow manual startup with
#         pg_ctlcluster
# disabled: do not allow manual startup with pg_ctlcluster (this can be easily
#           circumvented and is only meant to be a small protection for
#           accidents).

auto
```

You can then edit this file to make the cluster auto-start or not at boot.

---

On the other hand, if you have the postgres know-how,  it's possible to circumvent the Ubuntu's package way of handling PostgreSQL, and issue directly `initdb`, `postgres -D ...` as mentioned in the question, but then you should do it all the way and use your own startup script and configuration files.

Piggybacking on the packaged stuff for only a part of the admin work will tend not to work, for instance editing `/etc/postgresql/9.1/postgresql.conf` will not achieve much, as your custom `initdb` call will have created the `postgresql.conf` just under your `/data` directory, and a direct invocation of `postgres -D /data` will pick up that file, not the one under `/etc/...`